# What is the cleanest way to get the progress of JQuery ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

In plain javascript is very simple: need just to attach the callback to `{XMLHTTPRequest}.onprogress`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onprogress = function(e){
    if (e.lengthComputable)
        var percent = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
};

xhr.open('GET', 'http://www...', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    ...
};
xhr.send(null);
```

but I'm doing an ajax site that download html data with JQuery (`$.get()` or `$.ajax()`) and I was wondering which is the best way to get the progress of a request in order to display it with a little progress bar but curiously, I'm not finding anything usefull in JQuery documentation...

Comment: This one looks promising http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/ for html5

Comment: Ooh thanks guys! so need to override xhr.. the strange thing is that I've inspected with Chrome Dev Tools the so called `jqXHR` object (the wrapper of xhr object returned by `$.ajax()`) and found a `progress` attribute in it (along with `abort`, `complete`, `success`, etc.), but in JQuery docs this is missing: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: https://github.com/englercj/jquery-ajax-progress
I use this and its quite the same as other answers but I prefere to have more generic stuff

Answer (score 161):

Something like this for `$.ajax` (HTML5 only though):

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                //Do something with upload progress here
            }
       }, false);

       xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
           if (evt.lengthComputable) {
               var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
               //Do something with download progress
           }
       }, false);

       return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/",
    data: {},
    success: function(data){
        //Do something on success
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks promising, but how can this possibly work? The entire pipeline consists of three steps - sending a request, processing the request in the backend to generate some data, and return it back. How can the client side possibly know what is being done in the backend and how much time it will take that it can calculate the progress?

Comment: The HTTP response header tells us how many bytes to expect, this progress is simply counting how many bytes have been received so far.  It will stay at zero until the HTTP response is actually sent

Comment: Is it working only on POST, not also got GET and the others?

Comment: I also found https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758614/1286760 to be helpful and similar by design.

Answer (score 49):

jQuery has already implemented promises, so it's better to use this technology and not move events logic to `options` parameter. I made a jQuery plugin that adds progress promise and now it's easy to use just as other promises:

```
$.ajax(url)
  .progress(function(){
    /* do some actions */
  })
  .progressUpload(function(){
    /* do something on uploading */
  });
```

Check it out at [github](https://github.com/likerRr/jq-ajax-progress)

Comment: I liked the way you use the IFI factory. I did not knew that technique!

Comment: This is currently the best solution suggested here.

Comment: Working and elegant solution but you may be aware that it can break your existing code because it breaks all calls to the deprecated .success and .error. It also strips all non standard attributes you set on a jqXHR object. It does not provide also the context into "this" for the uploadProgress callback (maybe the same for progress but not tested) as it is done for all the standard promises for jqXHR. So you will need to pass the context in a closure.

Comment: I get error: `TypeError: $.ajax(...).progress(...).progressUpload is not a function` .... What's the issue?

Comment: @UniversalGrasp hi, please, open an issue at github and provide information about what you've done. This library wasn't updated for ages :) may be something has changed in jQuery itself

Comment: So glad somebody's done this. Hopefully eventually jQuery itself will just do it... amazing that it still doesn't do it out of the box.

Comment: The actual callback is `.uploadProgress(function(e) {})` @UniversalGrasp

Answer (score 6):

I tried about three different ways of intercepting the construction of the Ajax object:

1. My first attempt used `xhrFields`, but that only allows for one listener, only attaches to download (not upload) progress, and requires what seems like unnecessary copy-and-paste.
2. My second attempt attached a `progress` function to the returned promise, but I had to maintain my own array of handlers.  I could not find a good object to attach the handlers because one place I'd access to the XHR and another I'd have access to the jQuery XHR, but I never had access to the deferred object (only its promise).
3. My third attempt gave me direct access to the XHR for attaching handlers, but again required to much copy-and-paste code.
4. I wrapped up my third attempt and replaced jQuery's `ajax` with my own.  The only potential shortcoming is you can no longer use your own `xhr()` setting.  You can allow for that by checking to see whether `options.xhr` is a function.

I actually call my `promise.progress` function `xhrProgress` so I can easily find it later.  You might want to name it something else to separate your upload and download listeners.  I hope this helps someone even if the original poster already got what he needed.

```
(function extend_jQuery_ajax_with_progress( window, jQuery, undefined )
{
var $originalAjax = jQuery.ajax;
jQuery.ajax = function( url, options )
{
    if( typeof( url ) === 'object' )
    {options = url;url = undefined;}
    options = options || {};

    // Instantiate our own.
    var xmlHttpReq = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    // Make it use our own.
    options.xhr = function()
    {return( xmlHttpReq );};

    var $newDeferred = $.Deferred();
    var $oldPromise = $originalAjax( url, options )
    .done( function done_wrapper( response, text_status, jqXHR )
    {return( $newDeferred.resolveWith( this, arguments ));})
    .fail( function fail_wrapper( jqXHR, text_status, error )
    {return( $newDeferred.rejectWith( this, arguments ));})
    .progress( function progress_wrapper()
    {
        window.console.warn( "Whoa, jQuery started actually using deferred progress to report Ajax progress!" );
        return( $newDeferred.notifyWith( this, arguments ));
    });

    var $newPromise = $newDeferred.promise();
    // Extend our own.
    $newPromise.progress = function( handler )
    {
        xmlHttpReq.addEventListener( 'progress', function download_progress( evt )
        {
            //window.console.debug( "download_progress", evt );
            handler.apply( this, [evt]);
        }, false );
        xmlHttpReq.upload.addEventListener( 'progress', function upload_progress( evt )
        {
            //window.console.debug( "upload_progress", evt );
            handler.apply( this, [evt]);
        }, false );
        return( this );
    };
    return( $newPromise );
};
})( window, jQuery );
```

Comment: So I just tried implementing your solution but this code is a little bit too pro for me to understand - how do I use this? I copy pasted your whole code before my document.ready and tried doing `$.ajax({ ... }).progress(function(evl) { console.log(evl); });` but nothing is happening. Can you help me? :)

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @FloSchild, please do not edit my code just for the sake of your own formatting preferences.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has an [`AjaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) function that allows you to register global ajax handlers such as `beforeSend` and `complete` for all ajax calls as well as allow you to access the `xhr` object to do the progress that you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for the link. Can you include an example in your answer?

Comment: $.ajaxSetup({ xhr: function () { console.log('setup XHR...'); } });

Comment: And an example that answers the question? I'm afraid I can't upvote an answer that leaves me doing a lot of fiddling and reading, especially when the linked page says nothing about progress. Honestly, I'm sceptical about this, especially given the warning on that page, that says 'Note: Global callback functions should be set with their respective global Ajax event handler methods—`.ajaxStart()`, `.ajaxStop()`, `.ajaxComplete()`, `.ajaxError()`, `.ajaxSuccess()`, `.ajaxSend()`—rather than within the options object for `$.ajaxSetup()`.' <http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/#entry-longdesc>

Comment: [From the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):  _Set default values for future Ajax requests. Its use is not recommended._

Answer (score 0):

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/show-progress-report-for-long-running-php-scripts.html

I was searching for a similar solution and found this one use full.

```
var es;

function startTask() {
    es = new EventSource('yourphpfile.php');

//a message is received
es.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var result = JSON.parse( e.data );

    console.log(result.message);       

    if(e.lastEventId == 'CLOSE') {
        console.log('closed');
        es.close();
        var pBar = document.getElementById('progressor');
        pBar.value = pBar.max; //max out the progress bar
    }
    else {

        console.log(response); //your progress bar action
    }
});

es.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    console.log('error');
    es.close();
});
```

}

and your server outputs

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
// recommended to prevent caching of event data.
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); 

function send_message($id, $message, $progress) {
    $d = array('message' => $message , 'progress' => $progress); //prepare json

    echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "data: " . json_encode($d) . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;

   ob_flush();
   flush();
}


//LONG RUNNING TASK
 for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    send_message($i, 'on iteration ' . $i . ' of 10' , $i*10); 

    sleep(1);
 }

send_message('CLOSE', 'Process complete');
```

Comment: This shows progress of a running PHP script, not of an AJAX call.

Answer (score -4):

Follow the steps to display Progress of Ajax Request:

1. Create a Spinner using Html & CSS or use Bootstrap Spinner.
2. Display the Spinner when the end-user is requesting for the AJAX Data for infinite loop or for threshold limit time.
3. So, after a SUCCESS / ERROR result of AJAX Request, remove the Spinner which is currently displayed and show your results.

To make it easy I recommend you using JS Classes for dynamically Displaying & Hiding the spinner for this purpose.

*I Hope this helps!*

Comment: That is not "getting the progress" at all, only showing a "waiting" animation.

Comment: But we are looking for progress bar, showing percentage