# how to use ajax events in java

Tags: java, ajax

My question is relating to the server side using java servlet,
I have an ajax post with event listner like here:
[What is the cleanest way to get the progress of JQuery ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126994/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-progress-of-jquery-ajax-request)

How do I process this event listener in a java servlet, and what version of java I need for that

Comment: Java is on serverside, Jquery on client side.

Comment: Ajax sends request to a server; it has nothing to do with how the server will handle the request. 
it should work with any version of Java. What webserver are you using? (and framework? if you are using any)

Comment: try http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/04/jquery-ajax-request-response-java.html

Comment: my question is about processing the ajax request on the servre side using a java servlet without a framework, but specifically to ajax events, so if my front end is like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19127053/2660323  how do i service the progress event on the server side...