# abort one ajax request in multiple ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i use ajax to upload multiple file.user can upload multiple file in the same time.how i can abort ajax only for one uploading file?
this is ajax :

```
areq=$.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                xhr: function() { // custom xhr (is the best)
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    //load
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
                        $("#msg").text('success !' );
                    }, false);
                    //error
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener("error", function(evt) {
                        // show progress like example
                        $("#msg").text('error !' );
                    }, false);
                    //abort
                    xhr.upload.addEventListener("abort", function(evt) {
                        $("#msg").text('abort !' );
                    }, false);
                    return xhr;
                },
            type: 'post',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: fd,
            success: function(data) {
               // do something... 
            }
        });
```

Comment: why do you think using a custom XHR object is the best, when the one jQuery supplies already has an `abort` method and can also give you progress updates?

Comment: I want to create a buttom for cancel upload file

Comment: you'd have to use a separate `$.ajax` call for each file

Comment: no i use a same $.ajax for all file

Comment: well, AFAIK you can't just cancel one of them, then.

Comment: it is possible .and i solved it .

Comment: then feel free to answer your own question to share the solution

Comment: had you tried using jQuery.ajaxTransport( dataType, handler ) functionality?
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxTransport/

Comment: xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                //Do something with upload progress here
            }
       }, false);

Reference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126994/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-progress-of-jquery-ajax-request

Comment: @Alnitak i share my solution

Answer (score -1):

maximum number for upload file is 10.so i define this variable at the first of js file:
var sssss,formaa,formab,formac,formad,formae,formaf,formag,formah,formai,formaj;
and save $.ajax to sssss .after $.ajax put this switch :

```
stra=$(this).parent().index();
        switch (stra) {
            case 10:
                formaa = sssss;
                break;
            case 9:
                formab = sssss;
                break;
            case 8:
                formac = sssss;
                break;
            case 7:
                formad = sssss;
                break;
            case 6:
                formae = sssss;
                break;
            case 5:
                formaf = sssss;
                break;
            case 4:
                formag = sssss;
                break;
            case 3:
                formah = sssss ;
                break;
            case 2:
                formai = sssss;
                break;
            case 1:
                formaj = sssss;
                break;
        }
```

stra is number of file that is uploading.when user click on cancel button this function called:

```
$("form span#stop").click(function(){
            stra=$(this).parent().parent().index();
            switch (stra) {
            case 10:
                formaa.abort() ;
                break;
            case 9:
                formab.abort();
                break;
            case 8:
                formac.abort();
                break;
            case 7:
                formad.abort();
                break;
            case 6:
                formae.abort();
                break;
            case 5:
                formaf.abort();
                break;
            case 4:
                formag.abort();
                break;
            case 3:
                formah.abort();
                break;
            case 2:
                formai.abort();
                break;
            case 1:
                formaj.abort();
                break;
            }
        });
```

stra is also number of uploading file .so i copy $.ajax to another variable and that variable consider for every file.

Comment: so you _are_ initiation a separate `$.ajax()` call for each file?  Didn't you ever hear of arrays?