# Loading message ActiveRecord progression "Please Wait, checking X out of Y records"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord

Sometimes, my Ajax's requests takes a lot of time to get an answer due to the number of rows.

Instead of doing a basic Ajax loading message or animation, is it possible to display the actual progression of the request?

For example, if I have 10,000 rows :

```
Please Wait, checking n°1 out of 10,000 records
Please Wait, checking n°100 out of 10,000 records
Please Wait, checking n°200 out of 10,000 records
Please Wait, checking n°300 out of 10,000 records
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think this resource can help you (JQuery):**

[What is the cleanest way to get the progress of JQuery ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126994/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-progress-of-jquery-ajax-request)

**Hope this helps!**