# using AjaxSubmit(), is there a way to send data without using a form element?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajaxsubmit

While using the `$.AjaxSubmit()`, `$.AjaxForm()`.... there are several advantages like for example **having a cross-browser** `uploadProgress` which is the main attraction.

I have tried several codes, for hours now, I really cannot get a way to reach the `server` and show `progress` successfully.

But the `AjaxSubmit` plug-in seems to to be more `progress` friendly.

**I.e the progress in this example** (using `$.AjaxSubmit()`): http://www.sanwebe.com/assets/ajax-image-upload-progressbar/

However, deep down the `source-code` of the plug-in, there is this line:

```
 method = $form.attr("method") || "get"; // line 100
      url = $form.attr("action");       // line 101
      data = $form.serialize();        //line 102
```

See link: https://github.com/bogdan/ajaxsubmit/blob/master/ajaxsubmit.js

Does this mean that to benefit `from` the features of this plug-in you must use a form element?... Is there a work around?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez no `progress bar` in the accepted answer in the link you gave

Comment: `$. AjaxSubmit` is for a plugin for jQuery specifically meant to target forms. If you just want to make a request to a server using `$.ajax` and track its progress, see [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126994/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-progress-of-jquery-ajax-request) or [this great blog post](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/)