# C# Webbrowser check if file is still uploading

Tags: c#, ajax, browser

Is there a way to check if the webbrowser is uploading a file?

I tried it with the `webBrowser.ProgressChanged` this event triggers on some websites but if the website is using AJAX to upload files, the ProgressChanged event doesn't trigger.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126994/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-progress-of-jquery-ajax-request

Answer (score 0):

Hi it doesn't trigger because you are not async getting information from AJAX. You're ajax need to return the value of progress and you will set it on the progress of your bar idk.