# Get progress of "get" ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making an ajax "GET" request to get google wikipedia data in my application. I want to get the progress in numbers to feed it to my loading progress bar. Is there any way to do this for "GET" request? All the solutions available are either for upload or "POST".

THis is my request code

```
let params = {
  'query': this.state.info_search_text,
  'limit': 10,
  'indent': false,
  'types': 'Person',
  'prefix': true,
  'key': 'AIzaSyDuttGdbTLwBlVWunqGPdgUrb1c2gXwPYk'
};

$.getJSON(service_url + '?callback=?', params, (response) => {
    this.setState({
        infoSearchResults: response.itemListElement,
        showLoadingBar: false
      }, () => {
       console.log(this.state.showLoadingBar)
      });
});
```

Comment: I can't flag this as a duplicate, but here is the link to an answer that already has it done for you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126994/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-progress-of-jquery-ajax-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126994/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-get-the-progress-of-jquery-ajax-request)

Comment: "$.getJSON(service_url + '?callback=?'" — It isn't possible with JSONP. You need to use XHR or Fetch.

Comment: @Quentin true....i did not know this. But how can this work without using websockets?

Comment: @messerbill — See the duplicate question

Comment: @Quentin this is quite awesome. - so the client will request and once the server started to respond the progress handler waits for new incoming "data parts"?